# Mysql invisible process?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Here is a table

```
Id   Date   Name     vendor
1   | 123  |  jungle     |  qwe
2   | 43   |  jungle     |  qwe
3   | 678  |  jungle     |  ewq
4   | 678  |  jungle     |  ewq
5   | 678  |  jungle     |  ewq
6   | 678  |  jungle     |  hgjghj
```

This script removes rows from the table that have duplicate values in the name column and also have the same vendor value. Leaving only one unique row. The script is also executed via XHR ajax call `$.post()`, after clicking a button on the front end.

```
$sql = DELETE x
FROM $table x
JOIN 
 ( SELECT vendors
        , email
        , MIN(lead_id) min_lead_id 
     FROM $table
    WHERE vendors = $vendor
    GROUP BY vendors
           , email
 ) y 
ON y.vendors = x.vendors 
AND y.email = x.email
AND y.min_lead_id <> x.lead_id;

mysql_query($sql, $conn);
echo json_encode($foo);
```

and the result

```
Id   Date   Name     vendor
1   | 123  |  jungle     |  qwe
3   | 678  |  jungle     |  ewq
6   | 678  |  jungle     |  hgjghj
```

Now with a table of 50k it finishes in two seconds. Or rather, it returns an ajax call via the `echo json_encode($result);`. Now at that point I assume the process is complete but after going into my mysql table and refreshing again and again, I find out that mysql is still running because the total number of rows reported in the table keeps changing as if its still running query.

How do I make `echo json_encode($result);` wait until the database is finished updating? Or is there a better way to resolve this? Thanks.

```
$("#complete_dedupe").live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    table_name = $('#IMEXp_import-selectTable-select option:selected').val();
    $.post("dedupevendor.php", {"table": table_name}, function(data) {
        count_dedupe = 0;
        count_dedupe = data;
        $("#dupe_vendor").append(count_dedupe);
        $("#tr2").fadeIn("slow");
        vendor = $("#vendor_hidden").val();
        $("#edit_par4").append(vendor);
    }, "json")
});
```

By continually refreshing phpmyadmin, the circled number changes for the duration of about less than a minute. This only happens right after I run my dedupe script and right after the script already returns from the ajax call. The picture is below

[image]

Comment: No, the whole thing is finished by the time control returns to PHP. `mysqld` is *always* running in the background, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: I made an edit at the bottom, to my post in response. I dont think thats it.

Comment: Where is `$foo`/`$result` getting computed? That may have something to do with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing a change in phpMyAdmin is that `Innodb` doesn't keep a running count of rows, like `MyISAM` does.

Instead of looking at the table summary, run this; it should change when you run your de-dupe script.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM auto;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(mysql_query($sql, $conn))
{
  echo json_encode($foo);
}
```

This way, data will be returned to the calling ajax script only after `mysql_query()` returns a value back, which should happen only after the function finished processing

Comment: `mysql_query` is already blocking, it won't return until it is done. Also, adding an `if` statement never makes an asynchronous method blocking fyi, the function will return regardless of the if statement surrounding it

Comment: erm...so what is your solution to the problem?

Comment: I actually wasn't the downvoter, I was merely just pointing out this fact to you. Regardless, providing feedback to an existing answer does not necessarily mean I know the answer...

Comment: I didnt mean to say that you were the down-voter :) sorry if I came across as sounding so. And I am genuinely puzzled why the echo statement would return back to the ajax call even before mysql_query returned..

Comment: It wasn't so much your comment as much as it was the 4 "mysterious" downvotes on pretty old answers I received at the same time. But I am pretty puzzled as well, hopefully somebody can figure it ou

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean? I get what you said now..but it wasnt me dude.